# parsing and processing the received messages properly in java udp

Tags: java, udp

my multiplayer tank game has an issue. the client side tanks are not drew properly. the last one senden from server is good. but the others are blinking. i found the problem in client. when parsing the messages it gets the tanks x, y coordinates and direction with right queue. but when i send them to draw method it gets the last one. when i write the x,y coordinates in draw method the vast majority of x and y's are belong to last tank. so the last tank doesnt blink but the others are blinking. here is my code;

```
 public void run() {
    byte[] data= new byte[1024];
    while(true) {
    try { 
         DatagramPacket packetreceived = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
    soket.receive(packetreceived); 
    messagereceived=new String(packetreceived.getData(),0,packetreceived.getLength());
    
    setmesaj(messagereceived);
    
    parsemessage(messagereceived);
    
    
    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //soket.close();
}}
public String incomingmessage() {
    return messagereceived;
}
public void setmesaj(String messagereceived) {
    this.messagereceived=messagereceived;
}

public void senddata(byte[] data) {
    
    try {DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length,host,port );
        soket.send(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void parsemessage(String messagereceived) {
    
    String[] msg= messagereceived.split(",");    
    if(msg[0].equalsIgnoreCase("playtank")) {
        
        
        
        tankno=Integer.parseInt(msg[1]);
        setTankno(Integer.parseInt(msg[1]));
        switch(tankno) {
        default:
        x=Integer.parseInt(msg[2]);
        y=Integer.parseInt(msg[3]);
        direction=Integer.parseInt(msg[4]);
        }
        
    }
    if(msg[0].equalsIgnoreCase("addnewtanks")) {
        this.tankno=Integer.parseInt(msg[1]);
        this.x=Integer.parseInt(msg[2]);
        this.y=Integer.parseInt(msg[3]);
        this.direction=Integer.parseInt(msg[4]);
        this.health=Integer.parseInt(msg[5]);
        this.say=Integer.parseInt(msg[6]);
        this.tip=Integer.parseInt(msg[7]);
    }
    System.out.println(this.x+"     "+this.y+"     "+this.tankno);
** when i write these values, it is written properly to console everything is ok**
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getdir() {
    return direction;
}

public void setdir(int direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
}

public int getTankno() {
    return tankno;
}

public void setTankno(int tankno) {
    this.tankno = tankno;
}

public void draw(Graphics g,Bufferedimagex bf1) {
    //System.out.println(this.x+"  "+this.y+"   "+this.tankno);
**when the values are written here most of the written value on the console is the third one (there are 0,1,2,3 tanks).**
    g.drawImage(bf1.sprite(this.getdir()*32-32, this.tip*16), this.getX(), this.getY(), 48, 48,null); 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have separate objects for each tank? It doesn't appear so.  It looks to me like you have one `run` loop to read messages for all 4 tanks, and all tanks are sharing the same class object fields.  If that is the case, then you are probably constantly overwriting the member fields when another packet arrives.

You should probably consider creating a separate Tank class.

EG.,

```
class Tank
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int direction;
}
```

Then, create an array, list, or map of tanks.

```
Tank[] tanks = new Tank[4];
for(int i=0;i<tanks.length;i++)
{
    tanks[i] = new Tank();
}
```

When you receive a message, you would have to choose what tank to update. Here is an example using an array.

```
String[] msg= messagereceived.split(",");    
if(msg[0].equalsIgnoreCase("playtank")) {
    tankno=Integer.parseInt(msg[1]);
    // Choose which tank to update
    Tank tank = tanks[tankno];
    tank.x=Integer.parseInt(msg[2]);
    etc...
```

By creating a separate object for each tank, you will keep each tank's data isolated from the others, and won't have a problem with data being overwritten.

Comment: thanks jamie. yes i have got a separate  tank class. i added the tanks to a arraylist. then initialize the tanks in game panel. but the result was same. so i added a draw method to client class to reach all values. the last is above but it doesnt work. i can see the tanks on the screen but the last one is clearly seen and the others appears in a frame and disappears quickly. they are moving around. their coordinates are changing.

Comment: Your `parsemessage` method gives no impression of saving the data to separate objects... it's just writing the data to itself: `x=Integer.parseInt(msg[2]);`.  Where is it selecting the tank object to update?